# cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.(Android Hilt)

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I want to use the "Ticker" model class in "OrderBookActivity" and "OrderBookViewModel".
I'm new to Dagger Hilt and I'm just studying it, please help me understand.
I can not understand what the problem is

error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.websocket_upbit.data.model.TickerDataSource cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements FApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.example.websocket_upbit.data.model.TickerDataSource is injected at
          com.example.websocket_upbit.domain.module.RepositoryModule.provideTickerRepository(tickerDataSource)
      com.example.websocket_upbit.domain.repository.TickerRepository is injected at
          com.example.websocket_upbit.view.ui.OrderBookViewModel(tickerRepository, ��)
      com.example.websocket_upbit.view.ui.OrderBookViewModel is injected at
          com.example.websocket_upbit.view.ui.OrderBookViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.example.websocket_upbit.FApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC �� com.example.websocket_upbit.FApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC �� com.example.websocket_upbit.FApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

My code:

FApplication.kt

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class FApplication : MultiDexApplication(), Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
...
}
```

OrderBookActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class OrderBookActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityOrderBookBinding, OrderBookViewModel, Ticker>() {
    override val viewModel: OrderBookViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun setup() {
        setBinding(R.layout.activity_order_book)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        FLog.e(model)
    }
}
```

OrderBookViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class OrderBookViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tickerRepository: TickerRepository,
    application: Application
) : BaseViewModel(application) {
    init {
        FLog.e(tickerRepository.getData())
    }
}
```

Ticker.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class Ticker : BaseModel {
    var type: String = ""
    var market: String = ""
}
```

TickerRepository.kt

```
interface TickerRepository {
    fun getData(): Ticker
}
```

TickerRepositoryImpl.kt

```
@ViewModelScoped
class TickerRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val data: TickerDataSource) : TickerRepository {
    override fun getData(): Ticker {
        return data.getData()
    }
}
```

TickerDataSource.kt

```
interface TickerDataSource {
    fun getData(): Ticker
}
```

TickerDataSourceImpl.kt

```
class TickerDataSourceImpl @Inject constructor(private val ticker: Ticker): TickerDataSource {
    override fun getData(): Ticker {
        return ticker
    }
}
```

RepositoryModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {
 
    @Qualifier
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
    annotation class type1

    @Qualifier
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
    annotation class type2

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideTickerRepository(tickerDataSource: TickerDataSource): TickerRepository {
        return TickerRepositoryImpl(tickerDataSource)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @type1
    fun provideTickerDataSource(ticker: Ticker): TickerDataSource {
        return TickerDataSourceImpl(ticker)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @type2
    fun provideTicker(ticker: TickerA): Ticker = ticker.getTickerClass()
}
```

TickerA.kt

```
abstract class TickerA {
    abstract fun getTickerClass(): Ticker
}
```